# How to reduce the degree of a matrix using a matrix in Popov form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, computational-complexity

Let $P \in k[x]^{m \times n}$ be a polynomial matrix in (row) Popov form (see [section 2.4 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01928.pdf)) of degree (maximum of the degrees of its entries) $d$. Now let $A \in k[x]^{\ell \times n}$ be another matrix. Consider the matrix $M = (P^T A^T) \in k[x]^{m+\ell \times n}$.

Then by using division with remainder iteratively and that $P$ is in Popov form, we are able to reduce the degree of $A^T$ inside $M$ by applying unimodular row operations on $M$ **while not touching $P^T$**. But doing so, we need to use $O(n^3d)$ operations in $k$.

> But I suspect that there is an algorithm to compute $LM = (P^TC^T)$ with $\deg(C) < \deg(P)$ only with $O(n^\omega d)$ where $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication constant. DO you know one?

So I would like to **fix $P^T$** and only use it to reduce the degree of $A^T$ inside of $M$.

To do so, we may use the asymptotically fast algorithms for computing

1. Popov form of a given matrix of degree $d$
2. a reduced left equivalent of a matrix of degree $d$ (which is weaker than Popov form)
3. a basis of the row space of a given rectangular matrix of degree $d$
4. a basis of the row kernel of a given matrix of degree $d$
5. the solution of a rational system $\lambda M = b$ for given matrix $M \in k[x]^{n \times n}$ of degree $d$ and $b \in k[x]^{1 \times n}$

which all have a running time of $O(n^\omega d)$ where we neglect logarithmic terms in $n$ as well as $d$.

I am grateful for any hint or comment with regards to my question. Thank you!